# ggplot selecting data according to row and column

Tags: r

Data is like:

```
     Genres     Class Track_Num
1     'pop' unpopular     24786
2    'rock' unpopular     18792
3     'pop'   popular     11631
4     'blue'  popular      6000
 ............
```

Now I'd like to only select Genres (like 'pop'),whose sum of unpopular and popular Track_Num is > 500, what should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can `group_by(Genres)`, create a new variable as the `sum(Track_Num)`, and then `filter()`:

```
library(dplyr)

# Recreating your dataframe
music <- data.frame(Genres = c('pop', 'rock', 'pop', 'blue'),
                    Class = c('unpopular', 'popular', 'popular', 'popular'),
                    Track_Num = c(24786, 18792, 11631, 6000))

music %>% 
  group_by(Genres) %>% 
  summarise(Total_Track_Num = sum(Track_Num)) %>% 
  filter(Total_Track_Num > 500)

#   Genres Total_Track_Num
#   <fctr>           <dbl>
# 1   blue            6000
# 2    pop           36417
# 3   rock           18792
```